# Using # in the link tag to navigate to a certain part of the page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, navigation, tags

I'm trying to go from one page to a certain point in another page. Specifically, I have a page that has a photo grid on it, and I want a user to be able to click on the photo and take the user to another page that displays the full size of the photo. I've got that done, but when it goes to the page, it goes to the very top of the page, but what I want is it to navigate down to where the top of the picture is at the top of the page. Here is what I've tried so far:

PeoplePhoto.aspx:

```
<asp:HyperLink  ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
NavigateUrl='<%#'~/PeoplePic.aspx?ID='+Eval("ID")'#1'%>'>
<asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" 
BorderWidth="1px"
BorderColor="#DDDDDD" 
Width="230px" 
Height="180px"
ImageUrl='<%# "photos/PeoplePhotos/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

PeoplePic.aspx:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="People Picture" 
   BorderWidth="1px"
   BorderColor="#DDDDDD"
   ImageUrl='<%# "photos/PeoplePhotos/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
```

I'm pretty certain it's a problem with my hyperlink format, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I also just tried '<%"~/PeoplePic.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID") %>#1' for the NavigateUrl value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url must be followed with the id of the region.
For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#Geography.

Instead of giving #1 you want to give the id of the image. ie image1.

```
~/PeoplePic.aspx?ID='+Eval("ID")'#image1'.
```

You have to generate urls appending the image id , so that the navigation will be possible.

Comment: Hmmm... It's telling me that it's a bad request HTTP error 400.

Comment: Nope, got it now. having it my "navigateUrl" property set to '<%#"~/PeoplePic.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")+"#1"%>' and then putting an anchor tag with an ID of 1 is what worked for me. Thanks Subin!